# How to have Multiple Validation Rulesets with jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a multi-part form with three different sets of validation (each fieldset). Each validation ruleset is defined such as:

```
var paymentValidation =
    {
        rules: {
            "cardInfo.NameOnCard": {
                required: true
            },
            ...
        }
        messages: { .... }
```

and then when I need to validate a specific rulset, I am trying to use

```
var validator = $(form).validate(paymentValidation)
if(validator.valid()) {....}
```

Except it appears that once I perform validation once with a ruleset, the other optionsets I pass in do not matter.

I've seen articles suggesting that I can validate the entire form and then check each fieldset. While that approach technically works I end up with validation messages for elements outside of my desired scope.

So I'm trying to figure out how to go about performing validation with various sets of rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19228699/1399001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/06/jquery-validation-with-asp-net/ worked for me. Cheers.