# jquery validation plugin rules with condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery validation plugin , I have a big form with "Save","Submit" buttons.
I have two sets of rules for two buttons.

1. whenever user clicks save button only valid rulesOne set of rules (mandatory fields email, password).
2. whenever user clicks save button only valid rulesTwo set of rules (all required fields).

Any one suggest please, how to develop like this ?

Set1 rules:

```
var rulesOne = { email : "required" .......}
```

Set2 rules:

```
var rulesTwo = {city : "required" ..........}

$("#form1").validate({
ignore : '*:not([name]),:hidden',
rules : rules});
```

If save button

```
if(this.id == "personal_save"){
  setOne rules test ?
else
// submit button (check all validations)
{
  setTwo rules test ?
}
```

Thanks 
Prasad

Comment: What you've asked is not only extremely vague, it's off-topic to ask for code without showing an attempt at this yourself.

Comment: I have added sample code can you please look at

Comment: Where is your HTML markup?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically turn validation on/off for any/all parts of a form with this plugin.

However, you can use [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to dynamically add, remove, or over-ride your rules at any time, giving you a similar behavior.

Then you can use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to test the form.

Put them each inside dedicated `click` event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize the plugin
    $("#form1").validate({
        ignore : '*:not([name]),:hidden'
        // no rules; rules are set dynamically below
    });

    // Save Button
    $('#save_button').on('click', function() {

        // dynamically set the rules
        $('input[name="email"]').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            ....
        });

        // remove all rules from the other fields
        $('input[name="city"]').rules('remove');

        // force a test of the form
        $("#form1").valid();

    });

    // Submit Button
    $('#submit_button').on('click', function() {

        // dynamically set the rules
        $('input[name="city"]').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            ....
        });

        // remove all rules from the other fields
        $('input[name="email"]').rules('remove');

        // force a test of the form
        $("#form1").valid();

    });

});
```

**Proof-of-concept DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/x6YWM/**

---

If you have many fields, you can make this easier by setting appropriate classes on them like `.ruleset1` and `.ruleset2`.  Then you can target them as a group with the `.rules()` method.  Just remember that you'll need to enclose them inside a jQuery `.each()` if the selector targets more than one element...

```
$('.ruleset1').each(function() {  // target multiple elements
    $(this).rules('add', {        // apply the rules to each
        required: true,
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to override the previous `max` rule for a certain field.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same problem and after a lot of research I came to a solution. It consists in using JQuery.extend to replace the rules property in settings of the validator.
I created a jsfiddle based on @Sparky 's one.   http://jsfiddle.net/rWsLy/

```
 $('#save_button').on('click', function () {

var settings = $("#form1").validate().settings;

    // Modify validation settings
    $.extend(settings, {
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
    });

    // force a test of the form
    $("#form1").valid();

});
```

I prefer this way because rules are specified in the same way as in validate method. Also I think, previous solution doesn't scale.